Do typical LiFePO4 BMSes react to voltage drop properly in case of charging high voltage cutoff?
Typical LiFePO4 BMSes have several protections:

Temperature protection (low, high)
High current / short circuit protection
Low voltage protection during discharge
High voltage protection during charge

...and good BMSes also balance the cells during charging, either passively (burning off energy from high voltage cells) or actively (by transferring energy from high voltage cells to low voltage cells).
If a battery pack is not balanced, it's very common to encounter high voltage protection during charge. It is possible for example after some storage that cells have had non-equal self-discharge rates, and some cells are charged to full before others, so if the high-voltage protection is 3.65 V per cell and you are charging a 24V pack at 29.0 volts, it's very likely that some cell hits 3.65 V first before the entire pack hits 29.0 volts.
My question is related to usage when charging, and occasionally encountering loads higher than the charging current.
If a pack is charged at 29.0 volts, with a maximum current of let's say 10 amperes, and suddenly you have a load of 100 amperes, the voltage starts to reduce.
How do typical LiFePO4 BMSes handle this situation? Do they instantaneously detect that the high voltage from charging was removed, and reconnect the pack immediately, or is there some kind of delay that would momentarily starve the 100 ampere load?
I only have a sample size of 1: a Chinese 24V LiFePO4 pack with a JBD BMS that seems to perform well. It cuts off at 3.65 V per cell (which can easily happen at 29.0 volts since the balance current in this BMS is so low), but it seems to perform well when reconnecting the back if there's a momentary high load. I tested with a 2000W inverter that if the inverter has suddenly higher current than the charging can provide, the pack is reconnected so fast that there's no dip in voltage below the pack voltage that would cause the inverter to turn off due to low voltage. An oscilloscope showed that the voltage didn't drop even momentarily below the pack voltage.
But are typical BMSes so good in this property, or is my JBD BMS an outlier? Is it expected from a BMS that if a pack is charged and some cell hits the high-voltage cutoff, that you can have sudden loads, higher than the charging current, and the pack is immediately reconnected? Or can you encounter problems when you charge and at the same time have momentary (higher than charging current) loads?


How do typical LiFePO4 BMSes handle this situation? Do they instantaneously detect that the high voltage from charging was removed, and reconnect the pack immediately, or is there some kind of delay that would momentarily starve the 100 ampere load?

The answer requires considering the BMS topology (single or dual port) and switch technology (solid state or contactors).  But, in any case, the answer is the same: if the battery is not empty, 1) the BMS doesn't have to do anything and 2) the load is not "starved" for a split second.
Let's take a single port BMS with solid state switches. The battery is charging and is at about 50 % SoC. The BMS sees that the battery can accept charge and can provide discharge, so it enables both charging and discharging. The moment the load starts drawing a current, nothing changes with the BMS: is still enables both charging and discharging. There is no instantaneous detection because nothing needs to change. The only thing that changed is that before the current was flowing from the port to the cells, and now the current is flowing from the cells to the port. But the BMS didn't have to do anything. And the load can draw current immediately.
Let's take a dual port BMS with solid state switches. The battery is charging and is at about 50 % SoC. The BMS sees that the battery can accept charge and can provide discharge, so it enables both charging from the charger port and discharging out of the load port. The moment the load starts drawing a current, nothing changes with the BMS: is still enables both charging and discharging. There is no instantaneous detection because nothing needs to change. The current into the charger port is still the same. The only thing that changed is that before the current out of the load port was 0 A and now it's 100 A. But the BMS didn't have to do anything. And the load can draw current immediately.
